# SSIS Package - A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent

Apologies for posting this as a new thread but the original became a little muddled.

I have a very basic SSIS package with one SQL Task and one Data Flow Task. These tasks use one package-level OLE DB connection. I have the package and project set to `EncrptSensitiveWithPassword`. The package runs fine in Visual Studio 2019 but doesn't run in SSMS following deployment to SQL Server 2016.

I created the package locally on my standalone machine (I have no network account). My deployment method was to copy the DTSX onto the server. Using a SQL Server account with sysadmin rights I then used SSMS to import the file to the SSIS Catalog and also set up at SQL Agent job using the file system deployment method.

Both deployments give me the same error on execution.

> A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.".  An OLE DB record is available.
>
> Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005   >
>
> Description: "Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].

I don't know why I get this connectivity error. I've tried using both the IP and static server name in my connection. I've checked that TCP/IP and Named Pipes are enabled in Configuration Manager, which makes sense otherwise I wouldn't be able to connect from my machine via SSMS.

I don't know what else to try. Any assistance would be great appreciated.

Comment: The error message is as basic as it is irrefutable: the machine you're running this on can't connect to the server specified in the connection string. This error specifically means that there's no TCP/IP connectivity, that is, port 1433 is unreachable (assuming the default instance, otherwise the problem may be that port 1434 is unreachable for the SQL Server Browser service, or that the port the instance is running on is unreachable). Check for firewalls, and whether DNS resolution is working correctly *on the server*.

Comment: As a troubleshooting step, verify TCP port connectivity from your SSIS package host independently of the application. This can be done with `TELNET 1433` or with this PowerShell command: `powershell -Command echo ((new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Client.Connect('YourServer', 1433)) 'success'`. If this fails, other common causes besides those @JeroenMostert mentioned are SQL Server is not running or not configured to allow remote connections.

Comment: Thanks, it's sorted. Jeroen, you pointing out the blinding obvious did the trick. For some reason the server could not connect to itself using its own static sever name. I got the systems chap to sort this out (we still have a small issue in that you can only connect using a SQL Server authenticated account) but at least the package can connect to the server and run successfully. I'm now trying to work out how to allow package parameters to be edited with the SQL Agent job so that I can change the target database on the fly. Any ideas?

Comment: If the server needs to connect to *itself*, what will always work regardless of configuration is any of `.`, `(local)` or `localhost`. The benefit of these is that they will connect using the local memory transport, which is slightly more efficient than TCP/IP.  As for package parameters, that's really a separate question and should be asked separately. The way this is done varies based on the SSIS version (2016 works quite differently from earlier versions, in terms of storing and configuring packages). If you do ask a new question, be sure to be specific about how you're deploying.

Comment: Also, as a minor tip: to address specific users, prefix their name with @ so they get a notification. Otherwise, the only way they'll see your comments is if they happen to return to the question (as I did). You will always see notifications for comments on your own questions or answers, but not otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, I worked out how to deploy properly. Simply building the project locally to create an ispac, then deploying in Integration Services Catalogs did the trick and allows me to edit my package variables. The one oddity is that it seems that you have to be connected to SSMS via a Windows authenticated account to be able to deploy to Catalogs. This is a slight problem for us at the moment because it means I have to do all the deployment on the box itself. I can only connect remotely via a SQL server authenticated account sue to our setup here. Thanks again for your help.